# Python multiprocessing deadlock when calling Condition.notify() before the other process is ready

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, conditional-statements

I have a producer and consumer process, and a shared memory region between them. I use the Condition object to signal the consumer process from the producer process when new data is available.

Current problem is the ArrayConsumer deadlocks on cond.wait() with the following trace:

```
Producer: (3, 3, 30, 100)
Producer Done
Consumer: (3, 3, 30, 100)
Consumer Waiting...
```

What is happening from my understanding is that the producer notifies the consumer before the consumer is ready to receive the notification, and therefore keeps waiting for the producer's notification. What is the best way to make sure the consumer will only be signalled when ready?

```
def ArrayConsumer(aArray, cond):
   print('Consumer:', aArray.shape)

   with cond:
       print('Consumer Waiting...')
       cond.wait()
       print('Waiting finished..')
       print('Consumer:', aArray[1, 1, 1, 1])

def ArrayProducer(aArray, cond):
   print('Producer:', aArray.shape)
   with cond:
       aArray.fill(1)
       cond.notify()
   print('Producer Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':

   # sharing numpy arrays
   csi = csiMatrix(3, 3, 30, 100)
   shared = sm.sharedmem.empty(csi.shape, dtype=complex)
   shared[:] = csi

   cond = Condition()

   p = Process(target=ArrayProducer, args=(shared, cond,))
   c = Process(target=ArrayConsumer, args=(shared, cond,))
   p.start()
   c.start()

   p.join()
   c.join()
```

Comment: Personally I think the "best" way is to not bother with `Condition` at all: use a `Queue` to send produced data to consumers.

Comment: I have multiple GB of data. A queue wouldn't be able to hold it or take too long to serialize and un-serialize.

Comment: If you have big data, then yes, a `Queue` object *may* be too costly (but you should measure this to see). As [noxdafox said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44084827/1256452) you can use an `Event` object, which is essentially a flag wrapped with a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Condition.notify` method is a noop if no one is waiting. You need to encapsulate your logic in a while loop and periodically check whether the data is ready. The Python documentation has a [P&C example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects). You would need to set a timeout to the `wait` method and check the data in your array at every iteration.

It's much easier to use a `Lock` and an `Event` which would avoid a long-polling mechanism.

```
def ArrayConsumer(aArray, lock, event):
    print('Consumer:', aArray.shape)
    print('Consumer Waiting...')
    event.wait()
    print('Waiting finished..')
    with lock:
        print('Consumer:', aArray[1, 1, 1, 1])
        event.clear()

def ArrayProducer(aArray, lock, event):
    print('Producer:', aArray.shape)
    with lock:
        aArray.fill(1)
        event.set()
    print('Producer Done')`
```

Nevertheless, I would highly recommend to use a `Pipe` or a `Queue` to implement the producer and consumer pattern. It's a much more robust mechanism.

Comment: Why would an event be more appropriate? I need a lock to prevent race conditions. I don't think I can pass multiple GB data structures through a pipe.

Comment: Yes you can. It still is the simplest way to achieve what you want to do. I will modify the answer to show how to implement P&C with a Condition.